How to use Pydantic 2 in Databricks runtime 14.3?
I want to use Databricks Runtime 14.3 LTS because it's supported until February 2027.

The problem is that Pydantic 2 requires typing_externsions greater or equal to 4.6.0.
Databricks Runtime 14.3 has typing_extensions version 4.4.0 installed by default,

So I get a conflict error when trying to run my do_whatever_script.py, even though I try to install latest version of typing_extension using the following commands:
dbutils.library.restartPython()

get_ipython().run_cell_magic('sh', '', 'pip install  typing-extensions==4.12.0')

Any suggestions on what to do?

are you using Azure databricks

Found out a way to programmatically install custom libraries on cluster level by using compute feature from databricks.sdk.service:
from databricks.sdk.service import compute

def custom_python_libs_to_install(libraries: List[str]) -> List[dict]:
    libraries_to_install = [
        compute.Library(
            pypi=compute.PythonPyPiLibrary(package=library, repo=<YOUR_ARTIFACTORY_INDEX_URL>)
        ).as_dict()
        for library in libraries
    ]

    return libraries_to_install


Note: Keep in mind that YOUR_ARTIFACTORY_INDEX_URL could be PyPI index URL or one which refers to an artifactory used by your private/ corporate organisation
Then you can use the library dictionaries returned by custom_python_libs_to_install as input for you job information, by using the libraries field inside tasks:
job_info = create_job_info(
            name=name,
            tasks=[
                {
                    "task_key": flow.metadata.name
                    "libraries": custom_python_libs_to_install(["typing-extensions==4.7.1"]),
                    "spark_python_task": {
                        "python_file": f"dbfs:/FileStore/utils/you_python_script.py",
                        "parameters": [your_param1, your_param2, etc],
                    },
                    **cluster_specifications,
                }
                for flow in flows
            ]
        )


Then, create the job with that information:

from databricks_cli.jobs.api import JobsApi
from databricks_cli.sdk.api_client import ApiClient

def create_job(
    api_client: ApiClient,
    job_info: Dict[str, Any],
) -> None:
    """Create the Databricks job via the API."""

    jobs_client = JobsApi(api_client)

    logger.info(
        "Creating job for %s.",
        job_info["name"],
    )

    jobs_client.create_job(job_info)
    

create_job(
                api_client=databricks_client, # of type ApiClient
                job_info=job_info,
            )


After these steps you should be able to see your custom libraries installed in the Compute session of Databricks UI:

